# How to overlay an element without white background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using this jQuery code for overlay

```
$("a[rel]").overlay({ top: '24%' ,
    mask: { 
    color: '#0f0f0f',
    loadSpeed: 200,
    opacity: 0.9
                },

closeOnClick: false ,
    effect: 'apple',

    onBeforeLoad: function() {
        var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");
        wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
    }
});
```

I want to overlay without white background image. I removed that image in CSS. still, empty image loads on execution. How to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should lead you down the right path:

- http://examples.kierdarby.com/jquery.tools/overlay-mask.html